# mysql - UPDATEing row based on other rows

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I'm looking to update certain rows based on specific criteria based on other rows. Lets say the table looks like this:

```
COLUMNS:   time              type     genre    doubles     triples
ROW 1:    2010.06.21 12:00    1        1        0            0
ROW 2:    2010.06.21 12:00    1        2        0            0
ROW 3:    2010.06.21 12:00    1        1        0            0
ROW 4:    2010.06.21 12:00    2        3        0            0
ROW 5:    2010.06.22 12:00    2        2        0            0
ROW 6:    2010.06.22 12:00    2        3        0            0
ROW 7:    2010.06.22 12:00    1        1        0            0
```

I'm looking to update the `doubles` and `triples` columns based on the following rules:

1) Only look to update rows where the `time=time` and `type=type` between rows (e.g. Rows 1,2,3 and rows 5 & 6).

2) Next count the # of different `genre`'s between those rows and if there are two different `genres` then change the `doubles` column to 1, or if there are three then change the `triples` column to 1. SO for example in the table above rows 1,2,3 would have `doubles=1` because between the three rows there are two different genres. Rows 5 and 6 would also have `doubles=1` because there is again two different genres between the rows. `Doubles` can =1 and `triples` can =1 but not both.

Now, I could write up some PHP based on these rules pretty easily I think, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it all in mysql? It seems like I'm always surprised the amount you can do from a SQL statement.

Maybe something like (two different statements for the `doubles` and `triples` column):

Doubles - `UPDATE myTable SET (doubles=1) WHERE time=time AND type=type` ... but then how would you account for rule #2 above (counting number of rows with unique genres).

Is this possible in mysql or is PHP just the right way to go here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do it in one query.  Using this sample table:

```
create table duotri (time varchar(100), type int, genre int, doubles int, triples int);
insert duotri values
('2010.06.21 12:00'    ,1        ,1        ,0            ,0),
('2010.06.21 12:00'    ,1        ,2        ,0            ,0),
('2010.06.21 12:00'    ,1        ,1        ,0            ,0),
('2010.06.21 12:00'    ,2        ,3        ,0            ,0),
('2010.06.22 12:00'    ,2        ,2        ,0            ,0),
('2010.06.22 12:00'    ,2        ,3        ,0            ,0),
('2010.06.22 12:00'    ,1        ,1        ,0            ,0);
```

The update statement should join to the GROUPed form to get the doubles and triples.

```
update duotri t1
inner join (
    select time, type,
     case when count(distinct genre) = 2 then 1 else 0 end doubles,
     case when count(distinct genre) = 3 then 1 else 0 end triples
    from duotri
    group by time, type) t2
   on t1.time=t2.time and t1.type=t2.type
set t1.doubles=t2.doubles, t1.triples = t2.triples;
```

Comment: thanks I'll play with this a bit and let you know how it works

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible using sub-selects and the `CASE` expression or by comparing the count to the count for a column, but it will be difficult due to the fact that MySQL doesn't let you select the table that's being updated in the subselect.

You can do it easily in a select (I'm giving the table the name of 'recordings', since you didn't specify it; giving samples in SQL rather than preformatted text is always helpful):

```
SELECT r0.id, r0.`time`, r0.`type`, r0.`genre`,
     COUNT(DISTINCT r1.genre) = 2 AS doubles,
     COUNT(DISTINCT r1.genre) = 3 AS triples
  FROM recordings AS r0
    JOIN recordings AS r1 ON r0.`time`=r1.`time` AND r0.`type`=r1.`type`
  GROUP BY r0.`id`, r0.`time`, r0.`type`, r0.`genre`
```

You could then use this as the basis for a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html) or a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html):

```
ALTER TABLE recordings DROP COLUMN doubles;
ALTER TABLE recordings DROP COLUMN triples;
ALTER TABLE recordings ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;

CREATE VIEW recording_genre_count AS
SELECT r0.id, r0.`time`, r0.`type`, r0.`genre`,
     CASE COUNT(DISTINCT r1.genre) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS doubles,
     CASE COUNT(DISTINCT r1.genre) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS triples
  FROM recordings AS r0
    JOIN recordings AS r1 ON r0.`time`=r1.`time` AND r0.`type`=r1.`type`
  GROUP BY r0.`id`, r0.`time`, r0.`type`, r0.`genre`;
  --Since the columns of recordings are functionally dependent on recordings.id,
  --you could use just "GROUP BY r0.id", but the above will work on other
  -- DBMSs
```

If groups change frequently, the view is a better choice. It also ensures data [consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_Consistency_%28computer_science%29#Consistency). If you have to run a query to update the `doubles` and `triples` columns, the DB will often be in an inconsistent state immediately after rows are inserted ([triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html) could help with this, but like sub-selects in `UPDATE`s, triggers have problems selecting from a table that's being updated). Views and queries also more readily allow for additional columns (e.g. `quadruples`) than a stored procedure.