# manipulating attribute values in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table of the following form:

```
id    valA    valB
1      0       0
2      0       1
3      1       0
4      1       1

And it goes on like that..
```

Attributes **valA** and **valB** will only have boolean values. I want to figure out a mysql query which will produce the following output:

```
id    result
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       D
```

Logic used here is:

```
if valA = 0 and valB = 0 then result = A
if valA = 0 and valB = 1 then result = B
if valA = 1 and valB = 0 then result = C
if valA = 1 and valB = 1 then result = D
```

I found this somewhat similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082515/set-column-value-based-on-distinct-values-in-another-column) but failed to relate it to this one.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select
    case 
        when valA = 0 and valB = 0 then 'A'
        when valA = 0 and valB = 1 then 'B'
        when valA = 1 and valB = 0 then 'C'
        when valA = 1 and valB = 1 then 'D'
        end as result
from 
    table
```

Answer (score 0):

`select id,case  when valA = 0 and valB = 0 then 'A' when valA = 0 and valB = 1 then 'B' when valA = 1 and valB = 0 then 'C' when valA = 1 and valB = 1 then  'D' end as result from  table1`

Comment: A good answer contains both sample code and an explanation as to why the answer works. The code formatting here also leaves a bit to be desired.

Comment: @Tanis.7x well, in this case, the "why" would be, "because this is the SQL language construct meant to do what you wanted."

Answer (score 0):

If you take valA and valB as two bits in binary system, then after converting them into decimal you can use the result as index to some list.

```
SELECT id, ELT((2*valA+valB+1),'A','B','C','D') AS my_result FROM table
```

Comment: While this is clever (and I like clever) this is also unnecessarily complicated.  I would expect this to be significantly slower than a `CASE` statement over a large dataset.